# Weights in convenience sample

Tags: survey

I am using the MarketScan data, which is a convenience sample. It provides a set of sample weights for analysis, which are computed for sample estimates to scale up to the total population with ESI(employer-sponsored insurance) in the MEPS (Medical Expenditure Panel Survey) data. My question is, should these sample weight be regarded the same as the sample weights from a probabilistic sample, which are adjusted for potential sampling bias and designed to reflect the underlying population? If not, then it seems I should stick with unweighted estimates when using these convenient samples.

Thanks!

Liming

Comment: No.  In my view, your data is just as well analyzed with or without these weights, since this is a convenience sample can ti would be difficult to make any valid inferences with it -- weighted or not -- without making some very strong assumptions which I doubt are met.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand any attempt to generalize the findings would be subject to sampling bias. But if I just want to look at the findings within the sample, then is weighted estimates preferred over unweighted estimates? The two are numerically different. I am just wondering if there are any theoretical reasons to choose one over the other.

Comment: I would chose none of them and use the raw data.